# disabling flash in smarty framework

Tags: php, flash, smarty

How do i disable the **Adobe Flash** plugin when using [Smarty PHP framework](https://www.smarty.net/about_smarty) without issues on the website (or even framework)?.

**Problem:** 
I am testing with latest Firefox and my Smarty system doesn't work because of the Flash plugin detection process. Buttons functionality doesn't do anything, it just hangs. The issue is still there when testing in other major browsers.

This is my code:

**1) Detect Adobe Flash plugin:**

```
protected function browserFlashEnabled() 
{
    if ( isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] ) && $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] > 0 ) 
    { 
        if ( !$this->cache->verifyEntry( 'flashPlayerVersion' , 'System' ) ) 
        { 
            $flash = array( 'flashPlayerVersion' => $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] ); 
            $this->cache->createEntry( 'System' , $flash ); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**2) Show menu buttons:**

```
protected function initializeSystemUserContext() 
{ 
    $this->requireInitializeScript('trimDataEntry.php'); 
    $this->smarty->assign( 'flashEnabled' , $this->flashEnabled() ); 
    
    //# Get the menus that will be displayed to the user 
    $menuLibrary = LibraryFactory::getInstance( 'Menu' ); 
    $this->smarty->assign ( 'menus' , $menuLibrary->getNavitems() ); 
    
};
```

Comment: **(1)** What exactly is _`"the flash on smarty framework"`_? **(2)** How to **re-create** your problem ? (or give better description of the problem to be fixed. We cannot see your screen).  Also check if it works on other browsers (maybe Firefox browser itself is the problem).

Comment: This my code and when i comment the flash part my buttons on the system disappear: protected function browserFlashEnabled()
 {
  if ( isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] ) && $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] > 0 )
  {
   if ( !$this->cache->verifyEntry( 'flashPlayerVersion' , 'System' ) )
   {  
    $flash = array(
     'flashPlayerVersion' => $_COOKIE[ 'flashplayerEnabled' ] 
    );
   
    $this->cache->createEntry( 'System' , $flash );
   }
  }
 }

Comment: protected function initializeSystemUserContext()
 {
  $this->requireInitializeScript('trimDataEntry.php');

  $this->smarty->assign( 'flashEnabled' , $this->flashEnabled()  );

  // get the menus that will be displayed to the user

  $menuLibrary = LibraryFactory::getInstance( 'Menu' );
  $this->smarty->assign ( 'menus' , $menuLibrary->getNavitems() );

Comment: Also check if it works on other browsers (maybe Firefox browser itself is the problem). all  of the browsers I get the same problem

Comment: I don't use Smarty myself so I can't guarantee a possible solution. Just confirm this: You don't want Flash plugin because you are not using any `.swf` (Flash) files? What happens if you disable or remove the second line in `initializeSystemUserContext` function? eg: `//$this->smarty->assign( 'flashEnabled' , $this->flashEnabled() );` so that it skips checking for Flash?

Comment: I'm struggling to find any references to Flash in the [Smarty source code](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/). How did you end up writing code `browserFlashEnabled()` to detect Flash plugin if you don't use any Flash files..?

Comment: Edited your post. Hopefully your question is now in queue to be **re-opened** by admins.

Comment: When i comment out this line: $this->smarty->assign( 'flashEnabled' , $this->flashEnabled()  ); all buttons on the system disappear. i am not the first developer to start with this system from the scratch but i need to make changes and maintain it

Comment: Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. Any help regarding to this.

Comment: **(1)** Is the "flash" of unstyled page content a different second problem? or **(2)** Is it why you first asked "How to remove Flash"? I ask, to know, which **one solution** solves your problem (or you now need two solutions)?